# Constructing a pandas DataFrame with columns and sub-columns from nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**What I have:**

A nested dictionary `a` of the following form

```
    a={
   "level1": {
           "t1":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":5,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":8
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":11,
                           "col2":8,
                           "col3":2,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        }
                   
                },
           "t2":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":5,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":8
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":11,
                           "col2":8,
                           "col3":2,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        }
                   
                },
           
           "t3":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":2,
                           "col3":3,
                           "col4":4
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":6,
                           "col3":7,
                           "col4":8
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":9,
                           "col2":10,
                           "col3":11,
                           "col4":12
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":13,
                           "col2":14,
                           "col3":15,
                           "col4":16
                           
                        }
                   
                }
              
        },
   
   "level2": {
           "t1":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":9,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":5,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":5
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":11,
                           "col2":8,
                           "col3":2,
                           "col4":13
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":20
                           
                        }
                   
                },
           "t2":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":5,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":8
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":11,
                           "col2":8,
                           "col3":2,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":4,
                           "col3":4,
                           "col4":9
                           
                        }
                   
                },
           
           "t3":{
                   "s1":{
                           "col1":1,
                           "col2":2,
                           "col3":3,
                           "col4":4
                           
                        },
                   "s2":{
                           "col1":5,
                           "col2":6,
                           "col3":7,
                           "col4":8
                           
                        },
                   "s3":{
                           "col1":9,
                           "col2":10,
                           "col3":11,
                           "col4":12
                           
                        },
                   "s4":{
                           "col1":13,
                           "col2":14,
                           "col3":15,
                           "col4":16
                           
                        }
                   
                }
              
        }
  }
```

That is, the keys labelled `"level"` are the primary keys of `a`, the ones labelled `"t"` are keys of the nested dictionaries in each `"level"`, and finally the keys labelled `"s"`. Now, corresponding to each `"s"` labelled key, there is a dictionary with four keys `"col1","col2", "col3"` and `"col4"` where the actual data reside.

**Objective:**

I want to construct a pandas Dataframe from `a` in the following way:

[Nested Dictionary into the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cySI.png)

That is, I want the `"level"` and `"t"` keys to serve respectively as the primary and secondary indices of the dataframe, and `"s"` and `"col"` keys to serve respectively as the primary and secondary columns of this dataframe.

**Methods I Tried So Far:**

I tried using `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` and `pandas.json_normalize` methods. There is already a solution to a similar question and it uses `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`, but I didn't get much help from that, because that uses the `"s"` keys in `a` as indices instead of primary columns in the dataframe, and I cannot understand how `pandas.json_normalize` works and hence could not get the desired result

Is there any function in `pandas` I can use which can achieve this directly? Also, I don't know if a pandas dataframe supports this type of columns.

I am using `pandas` version `1.0.5` on Python `3.8.3`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the base `pd.json_normalize` to load in your data into 1 very wide dataframe. From there you'll need to convert your columns into a `pd.MultiIndex` then you can stack your levels as needed. Here's what worked for me:

Reading the data:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(a)

# Print first 4 columns because dataframe is SUPER wide
print(df.iloc[:, :4])
   level1.t1.s1.col1  level1.t1.s1.col2  level1.t1.s1.col3  level1.t1.s1.col4
0                  5                  4                  4                  9
```

Now we need to convert our columns into a `pd.MultiIndex` by separating each column name on the "."

```
# Splitting the by "." returns an index of list objects. By using 
#  map(tuple) we change the nested lists into nested tuples
#  pandas detects the tuples and automatically creates a MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").map(tuple)

# Print first 8 columns because dataframe is still fairly wide
print(df.iloc[:, :8])
  level1                                   
      t1                                   
      s1                  s2               
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col1 col2 col3 col4
0      5    4    4    9    1    5    4    8
```

Now we can stack the first 2 levels of our columns to turn them into a row index:

```
# stack the first 2 levels [0, 1]
#  reset_index() to get rid of the outer level of the index since it isn't meaningful
out = df.stack([0, 1]).reset_index(0, drop=True)

print(out)
            s1                  s2                  s3                  s4               
          col1 col2 col3 col4 col1 col2 col3 col4 col1 col2 col3 col4 col1 col2 col3 col4
level1 t1    5    4    4    9    1    5    4    8   11    8    2    9    5    4    4    9
       t2    5    4    4    9    1    5    4    8   11    8    2    9    5    4    4    9
       t3    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
level2 t1    5    4    9    9    1    5    4    5   11    8    2   13    5    4    4   20
       t2    5    4    4    9    1    5    4    8   11    8    2    9    5    4    4    9
       t3    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
```

Comment: That works great! I noticed however that when doing the stack operation, pandas will reorder things alphabetically. Is there a way to do the same thing but keep the original ordering (say if using an OrderedDict)?